# Chrome and Edge display served PDF with gray dot in center on multiple machines. Firefox displays fine

Tags: pdf

Sometime in the last few days, Chrome and Edge started displaying PDFs from my website with a dark gray background and a light gray dot in the center. **The PDFs display fine in Firefox**. I have tried this on 4 PCs and one outside our internal network.

[Gray Dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNvFT.jpg)

I have not made any changes to the web server configuration. (Apache, CentOS)

There are no errors in the apache error log related to the PDF files I am serving.

Comment: care to share a link to one of these PDF? Are the files accessible? Is only the grey square with a grey dot displayed?

Comment: It doesn't matter the PDF. I tried downloading http://www.cvm.qc.ca/nspatz/Powerpoint/Presperf.pdf and putting it on my site and it still just renders with the gray dot.

Comment: I understand but could you give a link to this PDF on your site? To see how it behaves for me.

Comment: What happen if you download the PDF locally to open it with Acrobat or something else?

Comment: They display just fine if you download them.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Chrome and Edge don't want to load PDFs if the Content Security Policy has *object-src 'none'* set. I had to relax the CSP a bit by setting *object-src 'self'*